# AWS EC2 private IP seen by vendor sftp server

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ip-address

I have assigned a public elastic IP address to an AWS EC2 instance in my default VPC that I provide to vendors that require IP whitelisting. When I attempt to connect to the vendor's sftp server, they claim they are seeing the instance's private IP address as the source IP trying to connect to their sftp server, rather than the public elastic IP address.

I am trying to understand how that would be possible. I would appreciate any thoughts on how my AWS VPC or instance might be configured incorrectly.

Comment: I just did a quick test from a linux box with a public IP to an sftp server in another account and `tcpdump` is showing my public IP.  Think you can get them to share their logs?

Comment: If your instance has an EIP, and has only one ENI and only one private address on that ENI, and you have no VPC peering or private VPN connections to the vendor... then I'd call this "impossible."